# Java Ordered Hashable Collection

Tags: java, hashset

What java data structure is an ordered collection, provides the functionality constant time `contains` method of HashSet, and  provides constant time lookup by index much like the `get` method of ArrayList? Does the Java API contain such a thing? I considered using TreeSet, but according to the Java Docs those operations are O(log n).

Comment: A [`LinekdHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) perhaps?

Comment: Do you need constant-time insertion? If so, this isn't going to work, since a data structure like that would let you do a comparison sort in O(n) time.

Comment: When you say "ordered", do you mean sorted order, or do you mean some other order, like insertion order?

Comment: you won't find such collection in JDK. None of ordered or hash-based collections have access by index. You can write your own, but I doubt that O(1) random access for some sorted structure can be gained unless insertion is O(N)

Answer (score 1):

The Java standard library does not offer such a class, but you could implement your own without too much trouble.  It would be more or less the dual of `LinkedHashSet`: a `List` (maybe wrapping `ArrayList`) that maintains an internal `HashSet` for constant-time `contains()` processing.

The Collections API has classes intended to make it easy to implement 
collection classes; in this case I would look at implementing a concrete subclass of [`AbstractList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html).

**Update:**
On the other hand, if your idea is that the instances automatically maintain their elements in order, and/or that they disallow duplicate elements, then what you're talking about is not a `List` at all.  In that case you would want to consider implementing a concrete subclass of [`AbstractSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html) that adds indexed retrieval methods.  You could still wrap a `HashSet` and an `ArrayList`, but you would need to expend some effort to keep the list ordered on element insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Use [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html). It is Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order.

You will see up to O(n) complexity for insertion or checking the existence of an item in the hash set. However most times you don't see collisions and so in most cases it will be **O(1).**

Comment: Does LinkedHashSet support indexing?

Comment: Set interface does not have any direct methods such as indexOf() or get(). You need to parse the whole collection in order to search for a element. indexOf() and get() internally do the same only.

Comment: The OP requests constant-time element retrieval *by index*.  Although `LinkedHashSet` offers constant-time retrieval, it is only by key, not index.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks for setting us straight with our answers.